# Strange behavior of function Simd::Fill()

Tags: c++, memory-corruption, simd-library

I use function [Simd::Fill](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__filling.html#ga54fc3ed63731c6f0528a1ce9ac86b2a1) from [Simd Library](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/index.html). And it works fine in the most cases. But there is a strange behavior sometimes. For example, in this case:

```
#include "Simd/SimdLib.hpp"

typedef Simd::View<Simd::Allocator> View;

View Create(size_t w, size_t h, uint8_t color)
{
    View image(w, h, View::Gray8);
    Simd::Fill(image, color);
    return image;
}

int main()
{
    View image;

    image = Create(200, 150, 127);
    image.Save("image.pgm");

    return 0;   
}
```

Saved "image.pgm":

[image]

There is a strange noise in the image. It is similar to memory corruption, but I can't find where is it. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I found a mistake which leads to this behavior. 
Assignment operator [View& operator=(const View &view)](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_view.html#ade09f01a94c8f95b525ac2321de7af64) of [Simd::View](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_view.html) class assigns only reference to other image. So your function Create() returns reference to local object.

In order to create copy of the Simd::View you have to use function [Simd::Copy()](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__copying.html#gadc21a4c5957a3e002edaa04721d952e2) or method [Simd::View::Clone()](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_view.html#a20180798df36bad984a0073c1c3513a0).

Comment: Oh. It's my mistake. Thank you!